# Do employers sometimes consider candidates with experience in lieu of academic credentials they specified as a requirement in job posting?

Tags: interviewing, resume

I recently applied for a job and I have a question.

If they say in a job posting "Office Assisting certificate is an asset", does this mean they will only consider those with that academic credential to have the asset qualification, or do some employers flexible enough to also consider those candidate with years of experience in office assisting as candidates who meet the asset qualification ( in lieu of academic credential)?

Comment: Highly dependent on the employer. Would also depend on the other applicants. If that credential is important to them and they get 5 people that have it, they probably won't call you if you don't. But there is no harm in applying for a job even if aren't sure you fit all the qualifications they are looking for.

Comment: Please read the contents carefully. It's not an duplicate of my previous question. In my previous question I was asking if I have to meet all asset qualifications to be invited for an interview. In this question I am asking if employers sometimes consider candidates with experience in lieu of the academic credentials that they specify in the job posting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does this mean they will only consider those with that academic credential to have the asset qualification?

No, describing a qualification as an "asset" would indicate that they take it into consideration but do not require it. Companies that have an absolute requirement will generally make this very clear, to avoid wasting everyone's time.

> Are some employers flexible enough to also consider candidates with experience in lieu of qualifications?

Yes, I have worked at several places where requirements in the job spec have been flexible. Remember that the ultimate goal of the hiring manager is (or should be) to hire someone who can do the job well - a job spec is only an attempt to codify what that person would do and be like.

In the event that there are many applications, however, those who do not meet all requirements may be culled without further consideration in order to reduce the scope of work for the hiring company.

In this case, it sounds like they do not have a hard requirement for the certificate, and would consider your application.